# Variation of orbital energy with atomic number

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms

I have come across the statement in an examination that “the energy of a given orbital with the same principal quantum number decreases as the atomic number increases”; but I couldn't understand why.

As I understand it :- In atoms containing multiple electrons we have to incorporate the inter-electronic repulsions into the wavefunction. But, the Schrödinger equation then becomes unsolvable and we can only approximate it. Using this approximation we could break down our wavefunction into separate wave functions for each electron which we call “orbitals” . But how could we possibly compare the energy of a particular orbital analytically without actually calculating it if the number of electrons differ? (i.e atomic number is different).

Comment: It's a confusing statement, since binding energy is negative. If we're talking magnitude: Moseley's Law disagrees.